# Change worksheet tab color if range of cells contains text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have tried code that I've found here on stackoverflow, and elsewhere but they aren't working as I think they can. I'll list them below. I'm almost certain this is an easy question.

**What I'm trying to do:** If in any of the cells in the range A2:A100 there is any text or number whatsoever, then make the worksheet tab red. And I will need to do this on over 20 tabs. This must execute upon opening the workbook, and thus not require manually changing a cell or recalculating.

**The problems I've had with other code:** As far as I can tell they require editing a cell, and then quickly hitting enter again. I tried SHIFT + F9 to recalculate, but this had no effect, as I think this is only for formulas. Code 1 seems to work albeit with having to manually re-enter text, but no matter what color value, I always get a black tab color.

**Code I've tried:**

*Code 1:*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MyVal = Range("A2:A27").Text

    With ActiveSheet.Tab
        Select Case MyVal
            Case ""
                .Color = xlColorIndexNone
            Case Else
                .ColorIndex = 6
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

*Code 2:* This is from a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733897/vba-how-to-change-tab-color-across-multiple-tabs-based-on-formula-cell-value) question, although I modified the code slightly to fit my needs. Specifically, if in the set range there are no values to leave the tab color alone, and otherwise to change it to color value 6. But I'm sure I've done something wrong, I'm unfamiliar with VBA coding.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("A2:A100").Text = "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 6
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

*I posted this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/900823/how-to-give-worksheet-tab-a-color-if-range-of-cells-contains-text) first, but perhaps stackoverflow is more appropriate since it is explicitly programming-related.*

Comment: The answer largely depends on when you want the code to run. Both of the examples respond to a specific event, which is why you need to change a cell or recalculate.  Do you need it to run on both changes and recalculations?  When you initially open the Workbook?  With some other event?

Comment: I need it to execute upon initially opening the workbook. Having it execute upon changes or recalculations is not an option. I've edited the OP to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two things will be able to switch the condition in this statement:

```
If Range("A2:A100").Text = "" Then
```

You've already identified both of them, changing the contents of the one of the cells in that range on a worksheet, or a formula in one of those cells recalculating to or from a value of "".  As far as event triggers go, if the formula result changes, ***both*** the WorkSheet_Calculate and Worksheet_Change events will fire. Of the two, Worksheet_Change is the one to respond to, because WorkSheet_Calculate will only fire if any of the cells in A2:A100 contain a formula. Not if they only contain values - your "Code 2" isn't wrong, the event was just never firing.

The simple solution is to set your tab colors when you open the workbook. That way it *doesn't matter* if you have to activate a cell in that range and change it - that's only way the value you're testing against is going to change.

I'd do something like this (code in ThisWorkbook):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In Me.Worksheets
        SetTabColor sheet
    Next sheet

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        SetTabColor Sh
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SetTabColor(sheet As Worksheet)
    If sheet.Range("A2:A100").Text = vbNullString Then
        sheet.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone
    Else
        sheet.Tab.Color = 6
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** To test for the presence of specific text, you can do the same thing but need to have the test check every cell in the range you're monitoring.

```
Private Sub SetTabColor(sheet As Worksheet)
    Dim test As Range

    For Each test In sheet.Range("A2:A100")
        sheet.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone
        If test.Text = "whatever" Then
            sheet.Tab.Color = vbRed
            Exit For
        End If
    Next test
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code works! I've only briefly had time to try it on one of my workbooks, but I have no reason to believe it won't work on the others. I'll report back to confirm. One thing, the color code `sheet.Tab.Color = 6` didn't work, all values there returned black. Replacing "6" with "vbRed" did work, however. **For those wondering exactly how to add this code:** Open the workbook. Press ALT - F11 to open the VBA editor. Near the top left you'll see the Project window. Scroll down till you see "ThisWorkbook", double-click. Enter the code. Save the workbook, and reopen.

Comment: @rebluriast - Yeah, I had no idea what color constant 6 was, so I just went with the value in the code from the question. Apparently 6 isn't black either - vbBlack is 0. Glad it's what you were after.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question. I'm now trying get the tabs to turn red only if a certain string of text is in the range. I thought replacing "vbNullString" with the string of text, and then replacing "xlColorIndexNone" with vbRed would do the trick (of course replacing the 'Else' 'sheet.Tab.Color = 6' to 'vbNullString' as well). But it's not working, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @rebluriast - If you're trying to match text in *any* cell in the range, you'll need to loop over the range and check them individually.  `If sheet.Range("A2:A100").Text = vbNullString` will only work if the entire range is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. The behavior I'm trying to achieve is as follows. If the text string, and only this text string = "lorem", color the tab red. Otherwise leave it.

Comment: apologize for the delay! Unfortunately this code isn't working. I don't get any change in the tab color by applying the code. I've tried applying it on spreadsheets with and without filtering, on individual worksheets, but to no avail. Just to be clear, I put the code from your edit in the 'ThisWorkbook' code by itself, not with the code from your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe test the len of the trimmed joined string of cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Len(Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A100"))))) = 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 6
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will fire off every time the sheet calculates though as it is event code, I am not sure if that is what you want? If not then post back and we can drop it into a normal sub for you and make it poll all the sheets to test.

Comment: Calculate only fires if the change the worksheet triggers a formula recalculation.  You can fill every cell row A, but as long as a formula isn't  entered and none of the cells are referenced in a formula elsewhere, this code won't run.

Comment: I based it on the code the OP posted, This sort of thing I wouldn't put at an event level personally but it's up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet_Change function will get called everytime there's change in the target range. You just need to place the code under Worksheet. If you have placed the code in the module or Thisworkbook then it wont work.

Paste the below in Sheet1 of your workbook and check if it works. Of Course you will need to do modification to the below code as I have not written complete code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WatchRange As Range
    Dim IntersectRange As Range
    Set WatchRange = Range("A1:A20")
    Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)
    If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
        ''Here undo tab color
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 6
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: OP doesn't want it to be reliant on a change: "The problems I've had with other code: As far as I can tell they require editing a cell, and then quickly hitting enter again."